# How to convert string to double in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am using a payments API in my application and am getting the invoice value with type number

**signature.invoice.amount:** 10500 (Number)

I tried to use currency pipe `{{ signature.invoice.amount | currency: 'BRL': true}}` and the transformed value is: **$ 10,500.00.**

But the transformed value should be $ 105.00 ... how do I get the number of the amount received to a monetary value in 'BRL' with a return of the number type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $105.00 is 10,500 cents, you want to convert it to dollars before transforming it:

```
{{ signature.invoice.amount / 100 | currency: 'BRL': true}}
```

Good job storing currency as cents though! That's the way to do it to save yourself errors down the line.